# Azure ML studio really slow

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I had been using Azure ML studio for a while now and it was really fast but now when I try to unzip folders containing images around 3000 images using

```
!unzip "file.zip" -d "to unzip directory"
```

it took more than 30 minutes and other activities(longer concatenation methods) also seem to take a long time even using numpy arrays. Wondering if it is something with configuration or other problems. I have tried switching locations, creating new resource groups, workspaces, changing computes(Both CPU and GPU).

Compute and other set of current configurations can be seen on the image

[image]

Comment: Could you please try to restart the kernel to see if it's better or not? I have seen this issue and this did the magic for me.

Comment: @YutongTie-MSFT sadly restarting the kernel didn't fix it. I went to prepare my dataset elsewhere, saved NumPy arrays of them, and went back to azure for training.

Answer (score 4):

When you are using a notebook, your local directory is persisted on a (remote) Blob Store. Consequently, you are limited by network delays and more significantly the IOPS your compute agent has.
What has worked for me is to use the local disk mounted on the compute agent. NOTE: This is not persisted and all the stuff on this will disappear when the compute agent is stopped.
After doing all your work, you can move the data to your persistent storage (which should be in your list of mounts). This might still be slow but you don't have to wait for it to complete.

Your local directory is /mnt/azmnt. So if you are using fiftyone to download your data set, your code would look like

```
import fiftyone
dataset = fiftyone.zoo.load_zoo_dataset(. 
              "open-images-v6",  
              splits=["train", "validation","test"],  
              label_types=["detections"],  
              classes=["Car"],  
              dataset_dir='/mnt/azmnt/openimages_cars_raw'
          )
```

Please make sure you use an *instance with large number of IOPS* to do the download part. You can convert to tfrecords (or any other format) and *copy it to persistent storage* and *register it in AML*. Then you can stop using this high cost instance and go back to normal instances.

Comment: Could you please extend the answer a little bit to give more details? I tried looking up documentation and searching but couldn't find detailed guide on how to do so.

Comment: Updated my earlier post and added details